# How to compile the face detection code in opencv2.4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I believe I have done all required changes in property pages. I don't understand how to manage the XML files need for face detection. What do I need to do with the XML files and where in the project folder should I put them?

Comment: Do you have issues compiling your code or issues running your code? You question is not very clear, and hence not likely to attract usefull answers. Please try to expand your question and improve your headline.

Answer (score 1):

The xml files defines the object that you would like to detect. (face/eye/ear/dog/etc.)
You pass the filename as a string to the `CascadeClassifier.load(...)` function.

have a look at the OpenCV tutorial, they detect both face and eyes with two separate Classifiers:
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier

```
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
   if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
   if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean. 
When you train your set of faces using Haarlike feature you have the xml file as result and then use this file to detect the face in images. That's all, it should not be confused.